# I'm trying to get the counter to work, how many months have a higher income than the same month from last year

Tags: c

The line of code I'm having trouble with has to do with counting a number of months, I'm passing a value up from a function that I thought would work but I'm not getting a proper readout from it. I'm sure I'm missing something stupid or the mistake I made is very basic but I can't seem to get it right. I would greatly appreciate any help I can get. please excuse the many `printf` statements, I was trying to find where the error was.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void DisplayInstructions();//function 1
void HigherSales(float yearOne, float yearTwo, int k);//fuction 2
int months (float yearOne, float yearTwo);//function 3

void main()
{
    float yearOne[12];//variables
    float yearTwo[12];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int count = 0;

    DisplayInstructions();//calling first function

    printf(" \n");

    for (i = 0; i<12; i++)//scanf for entering sales values 
    {
        j= i+1;
    printf("enter the sales figures for month %d in year one \n",j);
    scanf_s("%f",&yearOne[i]);
    }

        for (i = 0; i<12; i++)
    {
        j= i+1;
    printf("enter the sales figures for month %d in year two \n",j);
    scanf_s("%f",&yearTwo[i]);
    }                           //end of entering sales 

    k=0;
    for (i = 0; i<12; i++)//populating function 2 
    {
    k++;
    HigherSales(yearOne[i], yearTwo[i], k);
    }

    printf("\n count before going into the for loop is %d \n",count);

    for (i = 0; i<12; i++)
    {
    months(yearOne[i], yearTwo[i]);//populating function 3 
    printf("before going into count calculation months is reading %f",months(yearOne[12], yearTwo[12]));
    count = count + months(yearOne[12], yearTwo[12]); //calling function 3 so that i get the sum of times y1 < y2
    printf(" \n after calc count is %d \n after calc monts is returning %f", count, months(yearOne[12], yearTwo[12]));
    }


    printf(" \n the number of months in year two where sales have increased is %d \n", count);

        system("pause");
}
void DisplayInstructions() //function 1 printf's
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("this program consists of one function called 'DisplayInstructions' \n");
    printf("the function takes no arguments and simply dispays this message \n");
    printf("it is innitalised above main, called inside main and described below main \n");
}

void HigherSales(float yOne, float yTwo, int g)
{
    if(yOne < yTwo)     //function 2 comparing logic
    {
        printf("month %d in year two had higher sales than the same month the year prior \n", g);
    }
}

int months(float monthOne, float monthTwo)
{   
    int m = 0;
    if(monthOne < monthTwo )
    {
        m = m + 1;
        printf("\n in the mothhs function, m loop, m is %d \n", m);
        return m;
    }
}
```

Comment: These lines: `printf("before going into count calculation months is reading %f",months(yearOne[12], yearTwo[12]));
    count = count + months(yearOne[12], yearTwo[12]); //calling function 3 so that i get the sum of times y1 < y2
    printf(" \n after calc count is %d \n after calc monts is returning %f", count, months(yearOne[12], yearTwo[12]));` are all showing out of bounds array indexing.  i.e. if an array is created with 12 elements, the indexing range is `0` - `11`.  Did you mean to use `i` in these statements?

Comment: There is no `yearOne[12]`. The highest one is `yearOne[11]`.

Comment: In the function `int months(float monthOne, float monthTwo)`, there will be no return unless the condition `if(monthOne < monthTwo )` is true.

Answer (score 0):

The modified code below addresses the errors I commented under your post as well as some others (see comments in code.)  I automated inputs using `rand()` to speed up testing, but left all your original code.  Comment out the auto populate sections for your purposes.

*Note:* Not all logic errors are addressed, but enough to get you started.  Read the comments left in the code.:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void DisplayInstructions();//function 1
void HigherSales(float yearOne, float yearTwo, int k);//fuction 2
int months (float yearOne, float yearTwo);//function 3

const char month[][4] = {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};

void main()
{
    float yearOne[12];//variables
    float yearTwo[12];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int count = 0;

    srand(clock());//seed pseudo random number generator

    DisplayInstructions();//calling first function

    printf(" \n");

    for (i = 0; i<12; i++)//scanf for entering sales values 
    {
        j= i+1;
        printf("enter the sales figures for month %d in year one \n",j);
        yearOne[i] = rand();//Added to automate populating monthly sales numbers...
        while(yearOne[i] < 500)
        {
            yearOne[i] = rand()%10000;//Added to automate populating monthly sales numbers...
            Sleep(100);//pause execution for 0.1 seconds
        }
        printf("YearOne - %s: %lf\n", month[i], yearOne[i]);
        //scanf("%f",&yearOne[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i<12; i++)
    {
        j= i+1;
        printf("enter the sales figures for month %d in year two \n",j);
        yearTwo[i] = rand();//Added to automate populating monthly sales numbers...
        while(yearTwo[i] < 500)
        {
            yearOne[i] = rand()%10000;//Added to automate populating monthly sales numbers...
            Sleep(100);//pause execution for 0.1 seconds
        }
        printf("YearTwo - %s: %lf\n", month[i], yearOne[i]);
        //scanf("%f",&yearTwo[i]);
    }                           //end of entering sales 

    k=0;
    for (i = 0; i<12; i++)//populating function 2 
    {
        k++;
        HigherSales(yearOne[i], yearTwo[i], k);
    }

    printf("\n count before going into the for loop is %d \n",count);

    for (i = 0; i<12; i++)
    {  //Hint:  In this for loop, you are calling months function more
       //than you want to.  Consider assigning a variable to read it's
       //output, then use that variable in the printf statements. 
        months(yearOne[i], yearTwo[i]);//populating function 3 
       // printf("before going into count calculation months is reading %f",months(yearOne[i], yearTwo[i]));       
        printf("before going into count calculation months is reading %d",months(yearOne[i], yearTwo[i]));//changed format type to match variable type
        count = count + months(yearOne[i], yearTwo[i]); //calling function 3 so that i get the sum of times y1 < y2
        //printf(" \n after calc count is %d \n after calc monts is returning %f", count, months(yearOne[i], yearTwo[i]));
        printf(" \n after calc count is %d \n after calc monts is returning %d", count, months(yearOne[i], yearTwo[i]));//changed format type to match variable type
    }


    printf(" \n the number of months in year two where sales have increased is %d \n", count);

       // system("pause");
        printf("hit any key to continue.");
        getchar(); //this method  is more idomatic and portable to pause code
}
void DisplayInstructions() //function 1 printf's
{
        printf("\n");
        printf("this program consists of one function called 'DisplayInstructions' \n");
        printf("the function takes no arguments and simply dispays this message \n");
        printf("it is innitalised above main, called inside main and described below main \n");
}

void HigherSales(float yOne, float yTwo, int g)
{
    if(yOne < yTwo)     //function 2 comparing logic
    {
        printf("month %d in year two had higher sales than the same month the year prior \n", g);
    }
}

int months(float monthOne, float monthTwo)
{   
    static int m = 0;//use static here to allow m to keep value from call to call.
                     //static extends life of variable until program ends.
    if(monthOne < monthTwo )
    {
        m = m + 1;
        printf("\n in the mothhs function, m loop, m is %d \n", m);

    }
    return m;//moved from inside loop, otherwise return will not occur
             //for some evaluations.  
             //Perhaps you would prefer an else statement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `int months(float monthOne, float monthTwo)` does not work as you probably expect.

With `int m = 0;` the variable `m` always is initialized with `0` every time this function is called, therefore `m = m + 1` won't count up how often the condition is true - its either `0` or `1`

To make the function remember the value of `m` from its last call you need to declare it `static int m = 0;`
But in your case this wouldn't be the best idea either because you would only want to know the last return value (when all months are iterated).

Furthermore function `months` only has a return value if the condition is `true` - your compiler should have complained about that.

So if you want to make this simple comparison within a function which is called within a loop:

```
int months(float monthOne, float monthTwo)
{
   if (monthOne < monthTwo)
      return 1;
   else
      return 0;
}

for (i = 0; i<12; i++)
{
   count += months(yearOne[i], yearTwo[i]);
}
```

In your context I cant figure out the purpose of `count = count + months(yearOne[12], yearTwo[12]);` - beside the fact that you are accessing the 13th element of your array which is invalid, it makes no sense to increment your counter by the same comparison every loop.